# nginx rewrite : [emerg] unknown "0" variable

Tags: nginx, rewrite, centos6, php-fpm, ngx-http-rewrite-module

1.) Apache Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).htm$ /inner.php?Categories=$0&Title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

2.) After converting to nginx:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*).htm$ /inner.php?Categories=$0&Title=$1 break;
```

Question: 
When user access this page http://example.com/category.htm and tried to click  inside the pages means it should be redirect into
http://example.com/category/innerpagetitle.htm/

How do i achieve in nginx?

Answer (score 1):

In nginx variables are returned starting from `$1` so this should work:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*).htm$ /inner.php?Categories=$1&Title=$2 break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to implement these using `location` blocks.

```
location ~ ^/(.+)/(.+)\.htm$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /inner.php?Categories=$1&Title=$2;
}
```

I also changed from `.*` (0 matches or more) to `.+` (1 matches or more) to avoid possible undefined behaviour from the PHP script.